# RULE with multiple commands

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't figure out how to specify multiple commands for a rule. 
According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createrule.html), the syntax for creating a rule is:

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] RULE name AS ON event
TO table [ WHERE condition ]
DO [ ALSO | INSTEAD ] { NOTHING | command | ( command ; command ... ) }
```

As per this definition, I have tried to create the following rule:

```
CREATE TABLE "test" (
  "b" boolean NULL
);
```

-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE test AS 
ON UPDATE TO test DO INSTEAD 
(
INSERT INTO test (b) SELECT FALSE;
INSERT INTO test (b) SELECT FALSE;
)
```

However, what happens is very weird - this query fails to parse the first insert complaining about **syntax error at end of input LINE 4: INSERT INTO test (b) SELECT FALSE**, but at the same time executes the rest of the query, therefore incorrectly creating a rule with just one insert command.

Notes: My version is 9.0 and I have not found a single example of a multi-command rule anywhere.

So, how do I correctly define multiple commands for a rule? Is it even possible?

Comment: Did you try using a "regular" insert: `insert into test (b) values (false);` instead?

Comment: Yes, but it results in exactly the same thing: **ERROR: syntax error at end of input LINE 4: INSERT INTO test (b) VALUES (FALSE)**

Comment: One thing: you did not terminate the `create rule` statement with a `;`. If I do that, your code works for me (at least in `psql` - you might need to tell your SQL client that the `create` statement is a *single* statement not three individual ones)

Comment: I did try to terminate the whole statement but the query still failed - it just completely ignored the ");". However, this got me on the right track. I've tried to use psql directly and the rule creates fine there, so the bug is actually in the SQL administration tool I used (Adminer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, the problem lies in the database management tool I used - [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/en/). 
It somehow slices/corrupts the query, so you cannot create more than one command in a rule.

Note that this bug is present even in the (as of now) latest version 3.7.1.

Thanks a_horse_with_no_name for helping me resolve this issue.